# How to Toggle Mouse Hover Event on Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseenter, mousehover

I want to change the color of element on Hover. However I want to disable hover effect while clicking on the element and set the clicked element red. Again if anyone clicks on the element , and I want to enable the Hover effect and apply the hover effect.

```
$('.divElement').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
$('.divElement').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('red');
});
$('.divElement').on('click', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('red');
    $(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

I Have tried this jQuery Code.

```
<div class="divElement">Element 1</div>
<div class="divElement">Element 2</div>
<span class="divElement">Element 3</div>
<div class="divElement">Element 4</div>

.divElement {
    color: blue;
}
.divElement.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have tried is just to disable (`unbind`) the `Hover` event. What You actually need is to `toggle` the `hover` event if it is `clicked`.

First of all, I would like to suggest you, to change `<span>` tag to `<div>` or add `CSS` for class `.divElemenT{ display:block;}` else `inline-block` element and `block` element may hover at once.

```js
var hoverEvent= true;
$(".divElement").hover(
  function() {
    if(hoverEvent) $(this).toggleClass("red");
  }
);

$('.divElement').click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('selected');
   $('.divElement').not(this).removeClass('selected,red');// remove this line if you want multiple selector
   hoverEvent= !hoverEvent;
});
```

```css
.divElement {
    color: blue;
    display:block;
}
.divElement.red {
    color: red;
}
.selected{
font-weight:bold;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divElement">Element 1</div>
<div class="divElement">Element 2</div>
<span class="divElement">Element 3</span>
<div class="divElement">Element 4</div>
```

Please leave a comment if it doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me, but why the clicked element is bold??

Comment: @Ines I have added `selected` class and `.selected{ font-weight:bold;}` just to highlight the clicked element.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mousedown` event. Click responds after completing the click, `mousedown` works in between the click completion.

```js
$('.divElement').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(this).addClass('red');
});
$('.divElement').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(this).removeClass('red');
});
$('.divElement').on('mousedown', function () {
$('.divElement').removeClass('red');
    $(this).addClass('red');
    $('.divElement').off('mouseenter mouseleave');
});
```

```css
.divElement {
    color: blue;
}
.divElement.red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divElement">Element 1</div>
<div class="divElement">Element 2</div>
<span class="divElement">Element 3</span>
<div class="divElement">Element 4</div>
```

Comment: hover element should  be disable for all

Comment: Check the edits please. NO addition of extra css or classes. Works fine with the old ones.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a `hover` class which indicates that the class is hoverable. Then in your jQuery you can target elements with `.hover` class for your `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` leave events. This means instead of turning off the event listeners for your elements you can instead simply toggle the `hover` class for each element.

See working example below:

```js
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.divElement.hover', function() {
  $(this).addClass('red');
});
$(document).on('mouseleave', '.divElement.hover', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('red');
});
$('.divElement').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.divElement {
  color: blue;
}

.divElement.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divElement hover">Element 1</div>
<div class="divElement hover">Element 2</div>
<div class="divElement hover">Element 3</div>
<div class="divElement hover">Element 4</div>
```

**Note**: You need to use `$(document).on` as you are dynamically changing the classes after the event biding initially occurs, allowing you to listen to events on elements dynamically added/changed.

Comment: hover hasn't been disabled

Comment: @Ines when you click on an element it disables the hover and turns the clicked element red. Is this not what you were after?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach by toggle class "red" is correct. I just change a bit

HTML

```
<div class="divElement red">Element 1</div>
<div class="divElement red">Element 2</div>
<div class="divElement red">Element 3</div>
<div class="divElement red">Element 4</div>
```

CSS

```
.divElement {
    color: blue;
}
.divElement.red:hover, .divElement.selected {
    color: red;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$('.divElement').on('click', function () {
$(this).toggleClass('red selected');
});
```

The idea is only make the hover event in class "red", then we toggleClass red for element when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
$('.divElement').click(function(){
 if($(this).hasClass("red")||$(this).hasClass("selected")){
     $('.divElement').toggleClass("red");
     $(this).toggleClass("selected");
    }
});
```

```css
.red:hover,.selected{
      color: red;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divElement red">Element 1</div>
    <div class="divElement red">Element 2</div>
    <span class="divElement red">Element 3</span>
    <div class="divElement red">Element 4</div>
```

Comment: hover has not been disabled

Comment: i 'll fix it in one min